# How do I remove the 'dtype' being returned when using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting

I'm a bit new to python and I have to write a function for class. It receives a numpy array and searches through it for certain integers. I use doctests to test the return values from the function and I'm receiving the dtype in my results.

For example:

```
Expected:
array([1,2,3])

Got:
(array([1,2,3], dtype=int64),)
```

The function will be auto-marked, so I'm unsure how to have it return correctly.

I did some research and it was suggested to use numpy.astype to change the type to int32, however I receive an error when trying to do this as such.

```
myarray = myarray.astype('int32')
```

Is there any way to have it not show the dtype?

Comment: Can you please give full coding -- meaning, how did you create the value of myarray in the first place?

Comment: Which is wrong, the returned value, or the expectation?  In tests it isn't a good idea to tweak the returned values to match expectation, at least not without a good understanding of why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a tuple `(array([1,2,3], dtype=int64),)`. So when you try to do `myarray.astype('int32')` you are trying to call this method on a tuple. Maybe you are using `np.where` or another function that returns a tuple.

You either want to fix your function to return the array only, or do change that line of code to `myarray = myarray[0].astype('int32')`.

Also, you can't "remove" a `dtype` from a NumPy array. Every ndarray has a `dtype`. I am not sure why it is shown in your doctest though. NumPy test code often uses `np.allclose` to test array equality, so you may want to check this out if you have similar issues.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I knew it was a tuple, but I didn't know how to assign the astype.

Answer (score 4):

On my 32-bit Windows Python and linux 64-bit install, the dtype is printed when the numpy array uses an integer representation that is not the system default.

For example, on 32-bit windows:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
repr(test)
```

prints `array(1, 2, 3, 4)`, while

```
test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.int64)
```

has a string representation `array[1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64`

It is the other way around on the 64-bit linux install. It seems that you are on a 32-bit version, so int64 is not the default integer type.

It sounds like the solution you tried (getting the array as type int32) should work - what error message did you get? Perhaps try `myarray = myarray.astype(np.int32)`